# FFmpeg overlay one video to another, soung mixing, scale overlayed video and positioning it in right bottom corner

Tags: video, ffmpeg

When i execute this command:

```
ffmpeg -i screen.mp4 -i camera.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5" output2.mp4
```

I get this result:
[result image from video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CL9X.jpg)

It almost perfect, except one thing, i can't scale my overlay video(it is in the right bottom)I need to do it twice smaller.
Any help appreciated!Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filters. Example to make `camera.mp4` half size and mix the sound from both inputs:

```
ffmpeg -i screen.mp4 -i camera.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=iw/2:-1[cam];[0:v][cam]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5;[0:a][1:a]amix" output.mp4
```